# Is it possible to call a static method from withing another static method

Tags: python

Is it possible to call a static method from within another static method?

I tried this:

```
class MyClass(object):

    @staticmethod
    def static_method_1(x):
        x = static_method_2(x)
        print x

    @staticmethod
    def static_method_2(x):
        return 2*x
```

This returns

```
NameError: name 'static_method_2' is not defined
```

Comment: why don't you try?

Comment: I tried and the above doesn't work

Comment: So provide the details like what error you are getting

Comment: Do you really want all the questions to be so pedantic?

Comment: @LucaAmerio Yes, considering you wouldn't get a `NameError` if there were a global function named `static_method_2`; you would just call a function you weren't expecting to.

Comment: @chepner ok. But I usually assume my code examples to be executed in a clean workspace. So, in this example, there's nothing else but "My class" in the workspace

Comment: You might assume that, but we're not going to make assumptions about what we think you are assuming. Be explict; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Staticmethods are called via the class: `MyClass.static_method_2(x)`.

You probably don't want a staticmethod at all, but a classmethod. These are called the same way but get a reference to the class, which you can then use to call the other method.

```
class MyClass(object):

    @classmethod
    def static_method_1(cls, x):
        x = cls.static_method_2(x)
        print x

    @classmethod
    def static_method_2(cls, x):
        return 2*x
```

Note, in Python you wouldn't ever do this. There's usually no reason to have a class unless it is storing state. These would probably both be best as standalone functions.

Comment: Thanks. This is clearly just an example, while my class stores a state along with other functions.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, a class containing nothing except static methods is the closest thing Python has to an arbitrary namespace, which the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) claims is a good thing :)

Comment: @LucaAmerio I say that because people coming from Java, for example, often create non-instantiable utility classes like that where in Python we would just use a module.

Answer (score 2):

A static method must be invoked via the class that defines it; otherwise, that's just about the only difference between it and a regular function.

```
@staticmethod
def static_method_1(x):
    x = MyClass.static_method_2(x)
    print x
```

The reason is that the name `static_method_2` isn't defined in the global scope, or in any other non-local scope (remember, a class does not define a new scope). The static method is simply an attribute of `MyClass`, and has to be accessed as such.